how can we select a random text from a dropdown that has multiple div tags in playwright?
web element
is it possible to select a "random" text with div tags from a dropdown? because i am trying to select any random country from the dropdown using the code below in playwright:
const selectCountry = this.page.locator('<this locator>')
const randomCountry = faker.location.country()
await selectCountry.fill(randomCountry)

it is typing sometimes but it is not saving the value after the account submission. i guess it needs to select the value from the dropdown using mouse pointer or arrow keys but i don't know how to do it in a randomly manner.
i also tried the suggestions here: Playwright - select random option, with no luck. any help would be appreciated. thank you very much.

Please share a complete, runnable [mcve]. We don't have selectCountry() or the site under test, so there's no real way to help other than to toss out a random guess that probably won't fit your use case. Generally speaking, randomness is not a good property in tests so they're as idempotent and reproducible as possible. You should seed away any randomness as much as possible.

In the given screenshot there is no element of type select, while the select-random-option is about select element

Since in your screenshot there is no select element, you should try selecting the wanted option from the list using a simple click like in this example:
test(`select a movie`, async ({ page }) => {
  const movieName = "The Godfather";
  await page.goto("https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/");

  const movieDropDownLocator = page.locator("#combo-box-demo");

  await movieDropDownLocator.click();
  await page.getByRole("option", { name: movieName, exact: true }).click();
  await movieDropDownLocator.blur();

  await expect(movieDropDownLocator).toHaveValue(movieName);
});


thank you for your comment @ggorlen, but my lead is asking me to select a random country for my test not just a single country.

thank you @i-sh. i'll try the above implementation but i think this will also select a specific country every test run. but again, thank you and have a good one!
